# How to refactor function parameters and its usages

Tags: javascript, ide, refactoring

So i have method

```
function titleAndDetail(title, detail, lineHeight, lineLength, x, y, 
tFontSize, dFontSize, document, replacer){
}
```

I used it many, many times. And i figured out way that i dont need some of these params.

My goal is function like this:

```
function titleAndDetail(title, detail, lineLength, x, y, 
document){
}
```

My question is: Is it any way to refactor method and automatic delete these params where method is called to avoid do it by hand for hundreds times?

Im using visual studio code.

Comment: You could change your function to accept a single parameter, an object that has all those properties or only some of them.

Comment: Yes but then i need to change this in places where i used this function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this.

Either you can make it so that it accepts many parameters and ignores them if some are null. So you make the function that has all possible parameters, and then use it, and just set some to null. This can be seen in [TypeScript's "optional" parameter.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

A better way, which has been suggested, is to pass in a lambda JS object.
This can be done like this:

```
// Define it like this
function titleAndDetail(title, detail, lineLength, x, y, 
document) {
  // But instead you can check if title is actually something that defines all of these. Like this:
if(title.title != undefined) {
  passTitle(title.title);
} else {
  passTitle(title);
}

if(title.detail != undefined) {
  passDetail(title.detail);
} else {
  passDetail(detail);
}

}


// How you would use this and it wouldn't hinder the other uses of your function.
titleAndDetail({title: "title", detail:"detail", lineLength:"length", x: 43, y: 432, 
document: "document"});
```

Remember, you can pass in anything as the value for all of these.

Hope I helped..

Comment: My goal is to change structure of all usages of this function.

Comment: If for example i have three usages of this function in some place of my code i want to my ide or something other changed these 3 functions structure automatically

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge is not of Visual Studio :P. I can't really help you except point you to the "Find/Replace" button.